# how to compare two xml files and point out its difference in another file using perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, compare

**file1.xml**
`<Car>`
`<Name> Taurus </Name>`
`<Color> White </Color>`
`</Car>`

**file2.xml**
`<Car>`
`<Color> grey </Color>`
`<Name> Taurus </Name>`
`</Car>`

I am unable to distinguish and output the differences between both.plz help me out.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: why is this getting up voted?

Answer (score 5):

you can use `XML::SemanticDiff - Perl extension for comparing XML documents.`

`XML::SematicDiff` provides a way to compare the contents and structure of two XML documents. By default, it returns a list of hashrefs where each hashref describes a single difference between the two docs.

read in detail here 
[http://metacpan.org/pod/XML::SemanticDiff](http://metacpan.org/pod/XML%3a%3aSemanticDiff)